# Chrome equivalent for DOM .xml property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

Please have a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_node_xml.asp).
It says that .xml DOM property is Internet Explorer-only.

My question is- Is there any chrome equivalent for the same property?

Below is the xml that I am trying to parse-

```
<Message>
  <tag1 type=S1>
    <tag2>Text</tag2> 
  </tag1>
</Message>
```

What I want to achieve is to read the whole content of "Message" node in a variable as a string. Appreciate your help.

Thank You!

Comment: I am guessing from your tags that you are fetching this XML document from a Web page using Ajax. Is that correct?

Comment: @apsillers, you are correct. I am fetching the XML document using xmlhttprequest and trying to read the html tags in it. The html tags need to be passed to code further to build the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use XMLSerializer object in Non-IE browser

```
`function xmlToString(xmlInput)
{
   if (window.ActiveXObject)
      return xmlInput.xml;
   else
      return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlInput);
}`
```